# Django FormWizard Post to database with FK

Tags: python, django, forms, models, django-formwizard

I am using the Django Form Wizard and I have successfully created a multistep form that is able to create a new User. I have a second model called UserAddon that I set a OnetoOne relation to. I cant figure out how to POST to that model and to create that relation in the UserAddon. Also if someone knows, should I be using the checks like

```
if form.is_valid():
```

or

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Within this before I post?

Thanks!

Wizard

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "wizardApp/contact_form.html"
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        process_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('../home')
```

Process form data

```
def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    first_name = form_data[0]['first_name']
    last_name = form_data[0]['last_name']
    email = form_data[0]['email']


    print(last_name)
    print(first_name)
    print(email)

    user = User.objects.create_user(email)
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.email = email
    user.save()

    ##### SOMETHING LIKE THIS ####
    user_addon = UserAddon.objects.create(user.email)

    return form_data
```

Its also worth noting my code is written to set the users email address as the username

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figure it out see comment

Process form data

```
def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    first_name = form_data[0]['first_name']
    last_name = form_data[0]['last_name']
    email = form_data[0]['email']

    fav_food = form_data[1]['fav_food']
    fav_drink = form_data[1]['fav_drink']

    # print(username)
    print(last_name)
    print(first_name)
    print(email)
    print(fav_food)
    print(fav_drink)

    user = User.objects.create_user(email)
    user.first_name = first_name
    user.last_name = last_name
    user.email = email
    user.save()

    #######Solution HERE##########
    user_addon = UserAddon.objects.create(user=user,fav_food=fav_food,fav_drink=fav_drink)
user_addon.save()
```

I am still unclear on checking request for post and if the form is valid so any help there is still apreciated!